# An enrollment policy server could not be located

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, digital-certificate, csr, certenroll

I tried creating a PKCS10 request from another dll. In case of xenroll, the CSR got created successfully. Where as when i use certenroll, "An enrollment policy server could not be located" error is returned in the "InitializeFromPrivateKey" function call. Can someone help me out on why this error occur.

Comment: I have passed the template as NULL, which was causing this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass string.Empty it works.